# Unable to retrieve binary meta using DXA 2.0 and microservices

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, microservices

Using DXA 2.0 and micro services, the client application is unable to retrieve binary meta for a publication with publication url '/[clientname]/es'.

If client publication is /[clientname] and entry is in Broker DB, we can fetch Data through micro services without error.
But if we have client publication as /[clientname]/es, it error's out in client application.

The binary variant entry is published and entry exists in BinaryVariants table.

**Error in client application**

Unmarshalling entity for query: ODataClientQuery[GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http://localhost:8080/clientname/es/system/config/_all.json',ItemType='BinaryMeta')]

c.s.w.a.d.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Could not find Binary metadata by url: http://localhost:8080/clientname/es/system/config/_all.json

Can it be an issue with publication url having special character?

Comment: Deepthi, can you update the question with more info of the error? Provide the stack trace. Also, have you published the "Publish Settings" page from the publication with the client/es as the publication path?

Comment: How does the URL of the binary look in the Broker DB? And how does your Topology Manager config look (Website, WebApplication, Mappings)?

Comment: @Deepthi, Could you please run get the config info as Rick asked in the above comments, run this powerhell command on CME server and update your question for further understanding. Get-TtmWebsite and Get-TtmMapping

Answer (score 2):

The BaseUrl did not match the application URL. After adding application Url to list of BaseUrl's we got back spanish site content (e.g. client\es).